# NTFS partition suddenly unusable, "Error: end of file while reading /dev/sdX"

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

I have a Ubuntu box on an SSD and a secondary HDD (`/dev/sdb`) with some NTFS partitions.

Some context: yesterday the machine was unresponsive and I had to forcefully shut it down (cut power). On reboot Ubuntu would drop to Emergency mode. I found out that the HDD's UUID had vanished (did not show up in `blkid`), thus rendering `/etc/fstab` corrupt . I commented out the disk's line on `fstab` and managed to boot Ubuntu.

Now I am trying to mount the HDD again. First I tried Gparted. This is the output from libparted (used by gparted):

```
======================
libparted : 3.2
======================
end of file while reading /dev/sdb
The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will be used.
```

Interestingly, `sudo blkid` shows `/dev/sdb` as having a PTUUID instead of UUID:

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: UUID="e407bc1c-4c2d-4dae-80ce-e6bd96346698" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="659e6a1e-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="f9500440-cddf-41f6-8512-5a30e66fbf3d" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="659e6a1e-05"
/dev/sda6: UUID="18abc384-a610-4f65-8430-0109548a89ef" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="659e6a1e-06"
/dev/sdb: PTUUID="a6e9090d-b5ab-412a-8568-2eee08fa3fa8" PTTYPE="gpt"
```

I am confident that the partitions are still there, I just can't mount them. `parted` lists them correctly:

```
$ sudo parted
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) select /dev/sdb                                                  
Using /dev/sdb
(parted) p                                                                
Error: end of file while reading /dev/sdb
Retry/Ignore/Cancel? i                                                    
Error: The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will be used.
OK/Cancel? OK                                                             
Model: ATA ST1000LM024 HN-M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  316MB   315MB                EFI system partition          boot, esp
 2      316MB   945MB   629MB   ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 3      945MB   1079MB  134MB                Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      1079MB  979GB   978GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 5      979GB   1000GB  21,5GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag

(parted) q
```

So there are 2 errors (`Error: end of file while reading /dev/sdb`,`Error: The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will be used.`) which are likely rendering the partition unmountable. Any ideas how to solve them?

**EDIT** This is the output of `ntfsfix`:

```
$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb
Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

**EDIT** Output of gdisk

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Caution: invalid main GPT header, but valid backup; regenerating main header
from backup!

Caution! After loading partitions, the CRC doesn't check out!
Warning! Main partition table CRC mismatch! Loaded backup partition table
instead of main partition table!

Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged

****************************************************************************
Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
****************************************************************************
```

**EDIT** This is the command I wrongly executed which caused the trouble: `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 seek=1`

Comment: Try installing gdisk `sudo apt install gdisk`, then see if you can't repair it by running `sudo gdisk /dev/sdb`.  And when you can read the disk / partitions successfully, make sure you press `w` to write.

Comment: @Terrance I pasted the output of gdisk. Won't writing wipe out the data in the existing partitions? `Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!`

Comment: When you did the `sudo parted` you actually recovered the backup GPT partition, but you didn't press w before you quit so it would write the backup as the primary.

Comment: Yeah, I remember I was uncertain I should use `w` because of the same warning message which lead me to believe I would lose data.

Comment: Well, when the primary is damaged you don't have a choice but to overwrite it with the backup that is working.

Comment: Perhaps running `chkdsk` on a Windows recovery usb could fix the sectors without data loss?

Comment: You are more that welcome to try that.  I don't know if it will fix it though.  The gpt backup was created from the last successful boot of the drive.  It is created every time the system boots up.  All the messages I am seeing in your output are saying the GPT is damaged but the backup is valid.  And from the looks of it when you ran parted, it listed your partition fine.  In the future, you can always create backups of your GPT to help recover from disasters.  http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html

Comment: Thanks. I'm unfamiliar with gdisk: in layman terms, will restoring the backup GPT mean wiping out the existing data in the drive? I haven't changed the partitioning scheme in the disk for a long time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59412/discussion-between-brito-and-terrance).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TLDR: I was able to restore the disk (with data) by writing with `gdisk` (`w` command).

As was discussed in the question and comment section, this is the scenario: I had accidentally destroyed the GPT header of the disk by issuing a `dd` with 0s on `/dev/sdb`.

I ran [`gdisk(8)`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/gdisk) on the disk, which informed that the GPT header was corrupt, but the backup was fine and loaded the backup. In the `gdisk` CLI, I ran a `w` command (which writes the partition table information to disk) and exited. After that, `/dev/sdb` was instantly recognized and mounted by Ubuntu, and no other changes were necessary.